# Changing the form and arrangement of the workspaces

Tags: workspaces, gnome-classic

Lets say that I have 4 workspaces in a row, which are looking like this:

[image]

How can I make the workspaces look like this?

[image]

So, if I am for example (I'm talking about the purple figure) on the leftmost workspace and I press `ctrl + alt + RightArrow` and `ctrl + alt + DownArrow` , it should bring me to the downmost workspace.

I'm using `gnome classic` desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewports are always maxed out. You can choose columns and rows but they will then always line up to a total amount of viewports.

So 2x2, 3x2, 4,4 is all possible but you will never get a different number of viewports above than on the other rows below those 1st set of viewports.

The purple version will always result in 6 viewports (2x3).

Comment: Oh, ok then... I was pretty sure that this is possible but it seems that it isn't. Thank you! :)